# Can't differentiate with respect to the variable in python

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, sympy

```
import sympy
from sympy import *
from sympy import diff
import numpy as np

alpha = Symbol('alpha')
beta = Symbol('beta')
delta = Symbol('delta')
css = Symbol('css')
cssn = Symbol('cssn')
kssn = Symbol('kssn')

kssn = ((((1/beta)+ (alpha*delta) - 1)/(1-alpha)) + delta)**alpha
css = (((1/beta)+ (alpha*delta) - 1)/(1-alpha))*kssn
cssn = (((1/beta)+ (alpha*delta) - 1)/(1-alpha))*kssn

eps = 0.0001*np.abs(css)
eps1 = 0.0001*np.abs(kssn)

res = (1/css) - (beta/cssn)*(1 - delta + (1 - alpha)*(kssn**(-alpha)))
res1 = (1/css+eps) - (beta/cssn)*(1 - delta + (1 - alpha)*(kssn**(-alpha)))
res2 = (1/css) - (beta/cssn+eps)*(1 - delta + (1 - alpha)*(kssn**(-alpha)))
res3 = (1/css) - (beta/cssn)*(1 - delta + (1 - alpha)*((kssn+eps1)**(-alpha)))

x1 = diff(res1, css)
x2 = diff(res2, cssn)
x3 = diff(res3, kssn)

b1 = (x1 - x)/eps
b2 = (x2 - x1)/eps
b3 = (x3 - x2)/eps1
```

Error message:

```
  File "hw5.py", line 33, in <module>
    x1 = diff(res1, css)
  File "/Users/obrienstp/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sympy/core/function.py", line 1641, in diff
    return Derivative(f, *symbols, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/obrienstp/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sympy/core/function.py", line 1029, in __new__
    Can\'t differentiate wrt the variable: %s, %s''' % (v, count)))
ValueError: 
Can't differentiate wrt the variable: 0.0103498953698543, 1
```

Will anyone help me fix this? I am literally about to punch a hole in the wall. I am new to programming and have spent 3 days working on this. Why is it saying this error and how do i fix it?

Comment: Hi, it would help if you posted the full error message exactly how it's displayed.

Comment: You're defining `css`, `cssn`, and `kssn` as symbols, but then you're re-defining them as expressions, which means you can't differentiate with respect to them.

Answer (score 1):

When you get into a situation like this, use the interpreter to give you feedback:

```
>>> # what variables are in res1?
...
>>> res1.free_symbols
set([delta, alpha, beta])

>>> # what is css?
...
>>> css
(delta + (alpha*delta - 1 + 1/beta)/(-alpha + 1))**alpha*(alpha*delta - 1 + 1/be
ta)/(-alpha + 1)
```

As was noted, you can't differentiate with respect to an expression. You can only differentiate wrt a symbol (or function).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you first have

```
css = Symbol('css')
cssn = Symbol('cssn')
kssn = Symbol('kssn')
```

This defines the Python variables `css`, `cssn`, and `kssn` to be the SymPy Symbols `css`, `cssn`, and `kssn`. You then have

```
kssn = ((((1/beta)+ (alpha*delta) - 1)/(1-alpha)) + delta)**alpha
css = (((1/beta)+ (alpha*delta) - 1)/(1-alpha))*kssn
cssn = (((1/beta)+ (alpha*delta) - 1)/(1-alpha))*kssn
```

This overwrites the Python variables to reference the given expressions.  I can't tell you have to fix this because I'm not sure what you intended to do. For instance, when you write `res = (1/css) - (beta/cssn)*(1 - delta + (1 - alpha)*(kssn**(-alpha)))` do you want `css` in that expression to be `Symbol('css')` or `(((1/beta)+ (alpha*delta) - 1)/(1-alpha))*kssn`?

I think you are confusing how Python variables and SymPy Symbols work. Try to get this straight in your head, and you will avoid making similar mistakes in the future. There is more information about this at http://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/gotchas.html#symbols.

And as @smichr noted, doing things in an interactive terminal like `ipython`, `isympy`, or the IPython notebook will make things clearer to you because you will be able to see right away what your variables are actually equal to.